# Laravel Copy record and duplicate with new values

Tags: laravel

How can i copy a record and save it with a different value for 1 or more field?

for example:
get----> first_name, last_name, civil_status, work

i want to copy the first name, and last name then insert it with a new civil status and work.

Comment: The `replicate()` Eloquent method is what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 103):

You could use the `replicate` method of model like this:

```php
// Retrieve the first task
$task = Task::first();

$newTask = $task->replicate();
$newTask->project_id = 16; // the new project_id
$newTask->save();
```

Comment: does primary key id of auto increment nature does gets incremented automatically too when saving replicated model?

Comment: `replicate()` was introduced in Laravel 5.8

Comment: @padamthapa yes, it does

Answer (score 34):

You could use `replicate` method. This will create a new object with the same values except the primary key, and the timestamps. After that you can save your model:

```
$task = Task::find(1);
$new = $task->replicate();
```

If you want you could change a property

```
$new->project = $otherProject;
```

and then

```
$new->save();
```

if you want the new ID, easy:

```
$newID = $new->id;
```

Comment: No need to set `id` to `null`, or the `created_at` timestamp as that timestamp will be set on save.

Comment: It was an example on `created_at` attribute but now you speak the creation date probably get the same value of origin task, isn't? I don't remember when I needed to use. The same for the primary key.

Comment: @MiguelOliveira does primary key id of auto increment nature does gets incremented automatically too when saving replicated model?

Comment: $newID = $new->id;
it is not giving me id of the new record

Answer (score 14):

You can use `replicate()` and then update that row:

```
Model::find(1)->replicate()->save();

$model = Model::find(1);
$model->project_id = $new_project_id;
$model->save();
```

Comment: What about when you have several results...for example a user with several contacts info...or a post with several images in database relationship, and I need to replicate them?

Answer (score 10):

*also you can do like this.*

```
$selected = Model::find(1);
$copy = $selected->replicate()->fill(
    [
        'project_id' => $new_project_id,
    ]
);
$copy->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel replicate method for save same record or you can
say clone

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$newPost = $post->replicate();
$newPost->created_at = Carbon::now();
$newPost->save();
```